# how to provide completely multi-language support in my jsf application

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, internationalization, multilingual

I'm developing a web application and using `JSF 2.2` and `Primefaces`.

It contains a lot of output texts, user warning  messages etc. I want to support many different languages. What is the most usable way to do this? Is there any standard or efficient procedure to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF supports internationalized messaging through locale specific .properties resource files.  Once a locale is set, either implicitly via the browser or explicitly by the user, the appropriate bundle will be loaded.  For browser settings:

`<f:view locale="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestLocale}">`

You will also need to define the `<resource-bundle>` in you faces-config.xml where `base-name` defines the base file name and `var` defines the scoped result map.

I would start with this doc from @BalusC: http://jdevelopment.nl/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/

Also from @Mkyong: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-message-and-messages-example/

Comment: Thanks for reply @WitYoBadSelf . What do you think about charset of pages, these encoding types can be changed dynamicly? For example I have three properties files that contain Russian, Turkish and English clauses and I don't want to use "\u.." special definitions. I have one more question about that. I send some parameters(contain Turkish chars) via url,normally jsf page shows shapeless chars(for url params, not normal text in page ) but Turkish chars are defined UTF-8. Should I convert Turkish chars to codes passing with url ?